# Android build failed due to "compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED"

Tags: java, android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build APK for my project, but it fails without any error info.

**Version Info:**

- Ionic: 3.12.0
- Cordova: 8.0.0
- Node: 9.3.0
- npm: 5.6.0

**Notes:**
I had copied my codebase from my original one, renamed my project folder, removed .git folder, made app id changes in config.xml.

I also have google plus sign in configured in my ionic application which is configured correctly, I believe.

I tried removing, adding and preparing cordova android already.

Please, help me in solving this.

**Console:**

> ionic cordova build android --debug [INFO] Running app-scripts build:
>   --platform android --target cordova
>
> [15:24:01]  build dev started ... [15:24:02]  clean started ...
>   [15:24:02]  clean finished in 16 ms [15:24:02]  copy started ...
>   [15:24:02]  transpile started ... [15:24:10]  transpile finished in
>   8.44 s [15:24:10]  preprocess started ... [15:24:10]  deeplinks started ... [15:24:10]  deeplinks finished in 249 ms [15:24:10] 
>   preprocess finished in 250 ms [15:24:10]  webpack started ...
>   [15:24:12]  copy finished in 10.07 s [15:24:27]  webpack finished in
>   16.78 s [15:24:27]  sass started ... [15:24:30]  sass finished in 3.06 s [15:24:30]  postprocess started ... [15:24:30]  removed unused font
>   files [15:24:30]  postprocess finished in 16 ms [15:24:30]  lint
>   started ... [15:24:30]  build dev finished in 28.92 s
>
> > ionic cordova prepare android
> >     cordova prepare android
> >
> > cordova build android --debug | Running command [15:24:45]  tslint: ...:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/services/googletranslate/google.translate.service.ts,
> >     line: 2
> >                 'Headers' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { Http, Headers, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
>    L3:  import { GoogleTranslateResponse } from '../../models/google-translate-response';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/services/faq/faq.service.ts, line: 3
>               'Headers' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L2:  import { faq_data } from '../../models/faq'
>    L3:  import { Http, Headers, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
>    L4:  import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/guru/guru.ts,
>   line: 18
>               Property 'plt' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L17:  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private tts: TextToSpeech,
>   L18:    private plt: Platform) {
>   L19:    this.userName = navParams.get('userName');
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/guru/guru.ts,
>   line: 1
>               'Input' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { NavController, NavParams, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/pop-over-faq/pop-over-faq.ts, line:
>   68
>               'talkBackHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L68:  private talkBackHandler(e) {
>   L69:    this.enableTalkBack = !this.enableTalkBack;
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/pop-over-faq/pop-over-faq.ts, line:
>   78
>               'tapTextHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L78:  private tapTextHandler(text: string) {
>   L79:    if(this.enableTalkBack === true) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/list-faq/list-faq.ts, line: 43
>               Property 'faqService' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L43:  vCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private faqService: FAQService, public loadingCtrl: Loadi
>   L44:      public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, private storage: NativeStorage, private translate: TranslateService, private
> ```
>
> ngZone: NgZone,
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/list-faq/list-faq.ts, line: 45
>               Property 'alertCtrl' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L44:  public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, private storage: NativeStorage, private translate: TranslateService, private ngZone:
> ```
>
> NgZone,
>         L45:  private network: Network, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private tts: TextToSpeech) {
>         L46:  this.userName = navParams.get('userName');
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/list-faq/list-faq.ts, line: 240
>               'talkBackHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L240:  private talkBackHandler(e) {
>  L241:    this.enableTalkBack = !this.enableTalkBack;
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/list-faq/list-faq.ts, line: 2
>               'PopoverOptions' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  r, AlertController, NavParams, LoadingController, PopoverController, PopoverOptions } from 'ionic-angular';
>    L3:  import { FAQService } from '../../services/faq/faq.service';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/list-faq/list-faq.ts, line: 4
>               All imports are unused.
>
> ```
>    L3:  import { FAQService } from '../../services/faq/faq.service';
>    L4:  import { faq_data } from '../../models/faq';
>    L5:  import { GuruPage } from '../../pages/guru/guru';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/list-faq/list-faq.ts, line: 11
>               All imports are unused.
>
> ```
>   L10:  import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
>   L11:  import { LearnPage } from '../../pages/learn/learn';
>   L12:  import { TextToSpeech } from '@ionic-native/text-to-speech';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/learn/learn.ts,
>   line: 26
>               Property 'translate' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L26:  onstructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private translate: TranslateService,
>   L27:      private domain: DomainService, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private storage: NativeStorage,
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/learn/learn.ts,
>   line: 27
>               Property 'domain' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L26:  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private translate: TranslateService,
>   L27:    private domain: DomainService, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private storage: NativeStorage,
>   L28:    private tts: TextToSpeech) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/learn/learn.ts,
>   line: 111
>               'talkBackHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L111:  private talkBackHandler(e) {
>  L112:    this.enableTalkBack = !this.enableTalkBack;
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/learn/learn.ts,
>   line: 4
>               All imports are unused.
>
> / Running command        L3:  import { DomainService } from
>   '../../services/domain/domain.service'
>          L4:  import { Domain } from '../../models/domain';
>          L5:  import { ListFaqPage } from '../../pages/list-faq/list-faq';
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/services/api/api.service.ts, line: 27
>               Property 'plt' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L27:      constructor(private plt: Platform, private http: Http, private transfer: FileTransfer,
>   L28:          private storage: NativeStorage, private tokenService: UserService, private google: GooglePlus) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/services/api/api.service.ts, line: 239
>               'handleError' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L239:  private handleError(errorMsg: any) {
>  L240:      // Log error message in console
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/services/api/api.service.ts, line: 3
>               'RequestOptions' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L2:  import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
>    L3:  import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
>    L4:  import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject, FileUploadResult } from
> ```
>
> '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/services/api/api.service.ts, line: 6
>               All imports are unused.
>
> ```
>    L5:  import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
>    L6:  import { User } from '../../models/user';
>    L7:  import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/services/api/api.service.ts, line: 9
>               'Prediction' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L8:  import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
>    L9:  import { Prediction, PredictionResult } from '../../models/prediction'
>   L10:  import { AIResponse } from '../../models/airesponse';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/services/api/api.service.ts, line: 10
>               All imports are unused.
>
> ```
>    L9:  import { Prediction, PredictionResult } from '../../models/prediction'
>   L10:  import { AIResponse } from '../../models/airesponse';
>   L11:  import { UserService } from '../../services/login/login.service';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/camera-preview/camera-preview.ts,
>   line: 1
>               'ViewChild' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController, ModalController, Alert } from 'ionic-angular';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/camera-preview/camera-preview.ts,
>   line: 1
>               'ElementRef' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController, ModalController, Alert } from 'ionic-angular';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/camera-preview/camera-preview.ts,
>   line: 2
>               'Alert' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController, ModalController, Alert } from 'ionic-angular';
>    L3:  import { GuruPage } from '../../pages/guru/guru';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/camera-preview/camera-preview.ts,
>   line: 14
>               All imports are unused.
>
> ```
>   L13:  import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
>   L14:  import lodash from 'lodash';
>   L15:  import { ListFaqPage } from '../../pages/list-faq/list-faq';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/camera-preview/camera-preview.ts,
>   line: 15
>               All imports are unused.
>
> ```
>   L14:  import lodash from 'lodash';
>   L15:  import { ListFaqPage } from '../../pages/list-faq/list-faq';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/services/sync/sync.service.ts, line: 2
>               'RequestOptions' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
>    L3:  import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/home/home.ts,
>   line: 156
>               'talkBackHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L156:  private talkBackHandler(e) {
>  L157:    if(!this.toHighlightSpeaker) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/home/home.ts,
>   line: 168
>               'appIntroHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L168:  private appIntroHandler(e) {
>  L169:    if(this.isIntroInProgress) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/login/login.ts,
>   line: 63
>               'talkBackHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L63:  private talkBackHandler(e) {
>   L64:    this.enableTalkBack = !this.enableTalkBack;
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/login/login.ts,
>   line: 73
>               'tapTextHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L73:  private tapTextHandler() {
>   L74:    if (this.enableTalkBack === true) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/login/login.ts,
>   line: 298
>               'reload' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L298:  private reload(): void {
>  L299:    if (this.enableTalkBack === false) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/settings/settings.ts, line: 32
>               Property 'menu' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L31:  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private tts: TextToSpeech, public events:
> ```
>
> Events,
>         L32:  e: NativeStorage, private translate: TranslateService, private plt: Platform, private menu: MenuController,
>         L33:    private alertCtrl: AlertController, private camera: CameraService, private appAvailability: AppAvailability, private
>   market: Market) {
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/settings/settings.ts, line: 451
>               'talkBackHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L451:  private talkBackHandler(e) {
>  L452:    this.enableTalkBack = !this.enableTalkBack;
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/settings/settings.ts, line: 461
>               'talkBackTap' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L461:  private talkBackTap(option: string){
>  L462:    this.translate.get(['tts_settings_lang', 'tts_settings_cap', 'tts_settings_talk' , 'tts_settings_intro',
> ```
>
> 'tts_settings_sub']).subscribe((value) => {
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/settings/settings.ts, line: 2
>               'ToastOptions' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
> ```
>
> - Running command        L2:   NavController, NavParams, AlertController, MenuController, ToastOptions, Platform, Events } from
>   'ionic-ang
>          L3:  import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/services/update/update.service.ts, line:
>   25
>               Property 'plt' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L24:    constructor(private deploy: Deploy, private storage: NativeStorage, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
>   L25:    private translate: TranslateService, private tts: TextToSpeech, private plt: Platform) {}
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/welcome/welcome.ts, line: 92
>               'talkBackHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L92:  private talkBackHandler(e) {
>   L93:    // stop highlighting, if button touched in between TTS.
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/welcome/welcome.ts, line: 110
>               'tapTextHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L110:  private tapTextHandler(text: string) {
>  L111:    if(this.enableTalkBack === true) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/welcome/welcome.ts, line: 2
>               'IonicPage' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
>    L3:  import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/disclaimer/disclaimer.ts, line: 65
>               'talkBackHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L65:  private talkBackHandler(e) {
>   L66:    // switch enable-disable
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/disclaimer/disclaimer.ts, line: 76
>               'tapTextHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L76:  private tapTextHandler(text: string) {
>   L77:    if(this.enableTalkBack === true) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/disclaimer/disclaimer.ts, line: 2
>               'IonicPage' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
>    L3:  import { TextToSpeech } from '@ionic-native/text-to-speech';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/about-us/about-us.ts, line: 65
>               'talkBackHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L65:  private talkBackHandler(e) {
>   L66:    // switch enable-disable
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/about-us/about-us.ts, line: 76
>               'tapTextHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>   L76:  private tapTextHandler(text: string) {
>   L77:    if(this.enableTalkBack === true) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint:
>   C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/pages/about-us/about-us.ts, line: 2
>               'IonicPage' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>    L1:  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>    L2:  import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
>    L3:  import { TextToSpeech } from '@ionic-native/text-to-speech';
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/app/app.component.ts,
>   line: 336
>               'talkBackHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L336:  private talkBackHandler(e) {
>  L337:    this.enableTalkBack = !this.enableTalkBack;
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  tslint: C:/Workspace/ai-guru-app/src/app/app.component.ts,
>   line: 346
>               'tapTextHandler' is declared but never used.
>
> ```
>  L346:  private tapTextHandler(text: string) {
>  L347:    if(this.enableTalkBack === true) {
> ```
>
> [15:24:45]  lint finished in 14.88 s √ Running command - done!
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\gaurav.q.gupta\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151 :wrapper
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s 1 actionable task: 1 executed Subproject Path:
>   CordovaLib The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and
>   is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
>   Task.doLast(Action) instead.
>           at build_mxq2ksel8hq10p1rh0g2t3i7.run(C:\Workspace\ai-guru-app\platforms\android\build.gradle:137)
>   The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and
>   is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Incremental java compilation
>   is an incubating feature. The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has
>   been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please
>   use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead. :preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :checkDebugManifest
>   :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
>   :CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileLint
>   :CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets :CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig :CordovaLib:processDebugResources
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
>   :CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g.
>   outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
>   :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
>   :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
>   :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
>   :CordovaLib:bundleDebug :CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
>   :CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies :CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint
>   UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders :CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets
>   :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
>   :CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
>   :CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
>   :CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>   :CordovaLib:processReleaseResources :CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
>   :CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g.
>   outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   :CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
>   :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
>   :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
>   :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
>   :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
>   :CordovaLib:bundleRelease
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72600Alpha1Library
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library
>   :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library
>   :processDebugManifest :processDebugResources :generateDebugSources
>   :incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard :compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   :compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have
>   changed, no previous execution, etc.). :compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   FAILED
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 29.962 secs

Comment: does `ionic serve` work? also you might want to look at all the lint issues

Comment: @SurajRao Yes, ionic serve is working. You can go ahead in helping me ignoring lint issues as they were earlier in original project too.